# Current loop receiver (minimal implementation)

Tags: sensor, current-measurement, receiver

I'm looking for a minimal design of a current loop receiver with the following characteristics:

- I_in 0-20mA
- U_in (-24) 0 - 24V.
- U_out 0 - 3.3V

The precision doesn't need to be very high - an output voltage with a precision of +-5% proportional to the input current may be sufficient.

I was therefore looking first for a solution from a manufacturer and several forums. Unfortunately, I was not very satisfied with the solutions I found.

Either the presented solution was fully integrated within an IC and very expensive or it was too simple or too expensive, in terms of functionality:

### 1) Simple Shunt

The most frequently found solution was a simple shunt resistor with the high-side connected to an ADC or connected to a buffer and then to an ADC.
This solution is for me too error-prone in terms of failed connection or overvoltage.

### 2) Fully Integrated IC

This solution may be promising, but I'm looking for a more general solution. Maybe even cheaper.

I thought about an AC-input optocoupler, with the following benefits:

1. I don't have to share a common ground.
2. Isolated input.
3. Connection order doesn't matter.

Possible Problems with this solution:

1. Current-transfer-ratio seems to be in a wide range with low-cost optocouplers.
2. Current-transfer-ratio may be asymmetric.

Can someone recommend a possible solution or add some thoughts about my idea?

**EDIT #1**
After the first answers and comments I came up with this conclusion:
[image: Possible States]

I draw this picture, representing the mentioned states.

1. Normal operation.
2. Overvoltage, the voltage gets internally clamped and the protection resistor drops most of the overvoltage.
3. Pin swapped, the voltage gets internally clamped and the protection resistor drops most of the reverse voltage.

As I understand a TSV diode in parallel with the resistor would now only protect against fast voltage change if the internal circuit is not fast enough to react.
Therefore my next point is, what if the connection to the low side of the shunt resistor has a higher potential than the ground potential on my board. Wouldnt that lead to a ground loop carrying some current?

Comment: I must admit I don't understand what's error-prone about the shunt?

Comment: As mentioned in the first answer, a shunt is needed in most solutions.
So not the shunt itself is not error-prone. I thought about a minimal solution and the outcome if the inputs are swapped by accident. I would rather have a solution that is protected against pin swapping. Maybe a solution with protection will do the job or otherwise, a solution which amplifies the "normalized" input would be nice.

Comment: I don't understand: pin swapping in a current loop thing is a short – totally harmless. at most 20 mA flow.

Comment: EDIT #1: The voltage on the ADC side of the 2. state should be around 3.6V not 3.3V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I_in 0-20mA U_in (-24) 0 - 24V. U_out 0 - 3.3V*

That's basically a shunt resistor of value 165 Ω. No power supply needed. This is the minimal implementation. It's a totally viable and accurate solution.

> *The most frequently found solution was a simple shunt resistor with
> the high-side connected to an ADC or connected to a buffer and then to
> an ADC. This solution is for me to error-prone in terms of falls
> connection or overvoltage.*

Well, given that **any solution will use a shunt resistor**, all you have to do is ensure that it is protected. Protected from what is the next consideration and you haven't said but, given that any solution will use a current shunt resistor you face the same problem whatever route you choose.

Consider adding a 6.8 volt TVS in parallel with the resistor shunt then work out what the threat is in terms of surge energy and what level of protection you need. A reminder: you will have to do this on all and every solution.

As for protecting the ADC or op-amp or DAQ that may follow it, use a 10 kΩ series resistor and check that the follow-up circuit won't fry with a maximum input current of 6.8/10000 = 0.68 mA. OK, with a really big indirect lightning surge, you might need an SMC package device and the peak voltage during the surge might become 10 volts. But that is still only a silicon current of 1 mA and virtually any op-amp or ADC will survive this.

A simple shunt resistor is needed on all solutions so, not using a silicon interface and not using an interface that requires a power supply is fundamentally the most accurate solution.

Comment: also note that if everything works right, your shunt resistor needs to be able to deal with at most 66 mW of power; any 0603 resistor (0.002€ a piece) will do for that purpose (they typically can sustain 100 mW). Now, you can also just factor in overload situations, and overdimension your resistor (or resistor network: use N parallel strings of N 165Ω resistors in series each) sufficiently for this never, ever, becoming a problem.

Comment: Absolutely correct @MarcusMüller

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments.
Regarding the answer, I'm fine with the shunt itself. I wonder if there is a simple way to protect the ADC/MCU circuit against overvoltage, measured over the shunt.
Of course, some kind of diode may do the job, but what if the diode fails under the load. Further, how would one protect the circuit against input pin swapping?
I wonder if a solution with a shunt, which has to have a common ground connection with the ADC/MCU circuit may lead to a problem if multiple current loops are present with the different ground potentials.

Comment: The ADC/MCU protection I covered in my answer - a series resistor. (2nd to last paragraph). This is the standard way of ensuring that the input voltage to the ADC/MCU will not be exceeded. You might not be aware of that of course. Works for input swapping too. Current loops should not share common wires only a common star point at the receiver end.

Comment: It seems I may have a misunderstanding at this point.
In my perspective, the resistor in series to the ADC may protect it against a high current.
But in a "DC" perspective I would expect to have a zero voltage drop over the resistor if the capacity within the ADC is fully loaded. Therefore I would expect the same voltage over the ADC as over the shunt resistor. Is this a false expectation?

Comment: That expectation is reasonable. For normal signal levels the resistor will drop no voltage except when the input voltage level rises higher than the ADC's supply +0.3 volts or thereabouts. Of course I chose 10k but it may need to be 1 kohm if the ADC input produces offset currents that are problematic.

Comment: Would you agree with my edit, if so i'll mark this question as answered.

Comment: @MatthiasWaelti those additions are correct. You may even be able to make the resistor lower in vale if the ADC maximum limits allow higher than 1 mA current.

Comment: @MatthiasWaelti - do you remember your last comment "*Would you agree with my edit, if so i'll mark this question as answered*"?